# git cookbook fails to converge unless apt-get update is manually run

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm currently using the [Chef Supermarket cookbook for Git](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/git#readme). I'm also using test-kitchen to test my configuration before configuring an actual node with it.

I have a wrapper cookbook which implements the default.rb recipe of the Git cookbook. When I converge the sandbox machine (Ubuntu 14.04), with my specified recipes (in the kitchen.yml file), I receive an error explaining that:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing
```

If I log into the sandbox instance and manually run an `apt-get update`, then logout of the instance and re-converge, Git is installed successfully.

How might I fix this issue so that Git is able to be installed without manually logging into the machine being configured and running an `apt-get update`?

Answer (score 1):

In Chef you usually have a core recipe somewhere in your system that has an `apt_update` resource, which does the updating for you. We usually opt to not include this in every single community cookbook both because it increases per-platform bloat and increases the time overhead depending on system settings, generally makes it harder to control. So run this yourself from some base recipe or wrapper cookbook. In Chef 13 all you need is a literal `apt_update`, in Chef 12 you'll need `apt_update 'whatever'`. If you're on an early Chef 12 release you can use the `apt` community cookbook to do the same thing.

Comment: So I think I understand what you're saying. I currently have a wrapper cookbook for the Jenkins Supermarket cookbook, which depends on the Java SE and Git cookbooks. I'm just not sure exactly where I would specify the literal apt_update in order for the apt update to occur before the last recipe in the run-list (Git), is converged.

Comment: Pretty much, most people end up with a role or cookbook called something like `base` eventually, so it usually goes in there along with other global setup that is applied to all servers in your infra.

Comment: Hmm... Ideally, I'd like to just specify an additional recipe to run in my run list for the node which causes an apt_update. It seems like the most simple solution at this point (and can be reapplied as needed later on). Are there any cookbooks that have such a recipe? I've given Chef Public Supermarket a look, but didn't seem to be able to find anything there.

Comment: No, you write it yourself.